How to eliminate the burrs in the results of HSPICE simulation of CMOS composed xor gate
I encountered an issue while simulating a CMOS-based XOR gate using HSPICE. The simulation results show glitches occurring at the rising and falling edges of the input signals, especially when both inputs are transitioning at the same time. The glitches are particularly large in these cases. I believe this might be due to race conditions, and I have tried adding capacitors to mitigate the issue, but without success. I'm using a 32nm technology file for the MOSFETs. I have attempted two different methods to construct the XOR gate, but the glitches persist in both designs.
Here are the simulation results:

Here are the .sp file code and the MOS library:
XORtest.sp
XORtest

*MOS models*

.include 'LP32nm.mod'

VDD VDD 0 dc 1

Va A 0 pulse(0 1 0.01n 0.01n 0.01n 2.5u 5u)
Vb B 0 pulse(0 1 0.01n 0.01n 0.01n 2.5u 5u)

X1 VDD 0 A B Y xor
X2 VDD 0 A B Y1 xor1


.SUBCKT xor1 VDD 0 A B Y
Mp1 VDD A A1 VDD pmos W=320n L=32n
Mp2 B A Y VDD pmos W=320n L=32n
Mp3 VDD B B1 VDD pmos W=320n L=32n
Mp4 B1 A1 Y VDD pmos W=320n L=32n

Mn1 A1 A 0 0 nmos W=160n L=32n
Mn2 B A1 Y 0 nmos W=160n L=32n
Mn3 B1 B 0 0 nmos W=160n L=32n
Mn4 B1 A Y 0 nmos W=160n L=32n
.ENDS


.SUBCKT xor VDD 0 a b y
Mn1 a1 a 0 0 nmos W=160n L=32n
Mn2 b1 b 0 0 nmos W=160n L=32n
Mn3 y1 b b2 0 nmos W=160n L=32n
Mn4 b2 a1 0 0 nmos W=160n L=32n
Mn5 y1 b1 b2 0 nmos W=160n L=32n
Mn6 b2 a 0 0 nmos W=160n L=32n
Mn7 y y1 0 0 nmos W=160n L=32n

Mp1 VDD a a1 VDD pmos W=320n L=32n
Mp2 VDD b b1 VDD pmos W=320n L=32n
Mp3 VDD b a2 VDD pmos W=320n L=32n
Mp4 a2 b1 y1 VDD pmos W=320n L=32n
Mp5 VDD a1 a2 VDD pmos W=320n L=32n
Mp6 a2 a y1 VDD pmos W=320n L=32n
Mp7 VDD y1 y VDD pmos W=320n L=32n
.ENDS



*Simulation*

.OPTION POST=2
.TRAN 0.1u 20u
.PRINT TRAN V(B) V(A) V(y)

.END

LP32nm.mod
* PTM Low Power 32nm Metal Gate / High-K / Strained-Si
* nominal Vdd = 1.0V

.model  nmos  nmos  level = 54


+version = 4.0             binunit = 1               paramchk= 1               mobmod  = 0             
+capmod  = 2               igcmod  = 1               igbmod  = 1               geomod  = 1             
+diomod  = 1               rdsmod  = 0               rbodymod= 1               rgatemod= 1             
+permod  = 1               acnqsmod= 0               trnqsmod= 0             

+tnom    = 27              toxe    = 1.6e-009        toxp    = 1.3e-009        toxm    = 1.6e-009      
+dtox    = 3e-010          epsrox  = 3.9             wint    = 5e-009          lint    = 0             
+ll      = 0               wl      = 0               lln     = 1               wln     = 1             
+lw      = 0               ww      = 0               lwn     = 1               wwn     = 1             
+lwl     = 0               wwl     = 0               xpart   = 0               toxref  = 1.6e-009      

+vth0    = 0.63            k1      = 0.4             k2      = 0               k3      = 0             
+k3b     = 0               w0      = 2.5e-006        dvt0    = 1               dvt1    = 2             
+dvt2    = 0               dvt0w   = 0               dvt1w   = 0               dvt2w   = 0             
+dsub    = 0.1             minv    = 0.05            voffl   = 0               dvtp0   = 1e-011        
+dvtp1   = 0.1             lpe0    = 0               lpeb    = 0               xj      = 5e-008        
+ngate   = 1e+023          ndep    = 4.12e+018       nsd     = 2e+020          phin    = 0             
+cdsc    = 0               cdscb   = 0               cdscd   = 0               cit     = 0             
+voff    = -0.1144         nfactor = 1.6             eta0    = 0.0115          etab    = 0             
+vfb     = -0.55           u0      = 0.042           ua      = 6e-010          ub      = 1.2e-018      
+uc      = 0               vsat    = 155000          a0      = 1               ags     = 0             
+a1      = 0               a2      = 1               b0      = 0               b1      = 0             
+keta    = 0.04            dwg     = 0               dwb     = 0               pclm    = 0.02          
+pdiblc1 = 0.001           pdiblc2 = 0.001           pdiblcb = -0.005          drout   = 0.5           
+pvag    = 1e-020          delta   = 0.01            pscbe1  = 8.14e+008       pscbe2  = 1e-007        
+fprout  = 0.2             pdits   = 0.01            pditsd  = 0.23            pditsl  = 2300000       
+rsh     = 5               rdsw    = 190             rsw     = 75              rdw     = 75            
+rdswmin = 0               rdwmin  = 0               rswmin  = 0               prwg    = 0             
+prwb    = 0               wr      = 1               alpha0  = 0.074           alpha1  = 0.005         
+beta0   = 30              agidl   = 0.0002          bgidl   = 2.1e+009        cgidl   = 0.0002        
+egidl   = 0.8             aigbacc = 0.012           bigbacc = 0.0028          cigbacc = 0.002         
+nigbacc = 1               aigbinv = 0.014           bigbinv = 0.004           cigbinv = 0.004         
+eigbinv = 1.1             nigbinv = 3               aigc    = 0.015211        bigc    = 0.0027432     
+cigc    = 0.002           aigsd   = 0.015211        bigsd   = 0.0027432       cigsd   = 0.002         
+nigc    = 1               poxedge = 1               pigcd   = 1               ntox    = 1             
+xrcrg1  = 12              xrcrg2  = 5             

+cgso    = 8.5e-011        cgdo    = 8.5e-011        cgbo    = 2.56e-011       cgdl    = 2.653e-010    
+cgsl    = 2.653e-010      ckappas = 0.03            ckappad = 0.03            acde    = 1             
+moin    = 15              noff    = 0.9             voffcv  = 0.02          

+kt1     = -0.11           kt1l    = 0               kt2     = 0.022           ute     = -1.5          
+ua1     = 4.31e-009       ub1     = 7.61e-018       uc1     = -5.6e-011       prt     = 0             
+at      = 33000         

+fnoimod = 1               tnoimod = 0             

+jss     = 0.0001          jsws    = 1e-011          jswgs   = 1e-010          njs     = 1             
+ijthsfwd= 0.01            ijthsrev= 0.001           bvs     = 10              xjbvs   = 1             
+jsd     = 0.0001          jswd    = 1e-011          jswgd   = 1e-010          njd     = 1             
+ijthdfwd= 0.01            ijthdrev= 0.001           bvd     = 10              xjbvd   = 1             
+pbs     = 1               cjs     = 0.0005          mjs     = 0.5             pbsws   = 1             
+cjsws   = 5e-010          mjsws   = 0.33            pbswgs  = 1               cjswgs  = 3e-010        
+mjswgs  = 0.33            pbd     = 1               cjd     = 0.0005          mjd     = 0.5           
+pbswd   = 1               cjswd   = 5e-010          mjswd   = 0.33            pbswgd  = 1             
+cjswgd  = 5e-010          mjswgd  = 0.33            tpb     = 0.005           tcj     = 0.001         
+tpbsw   = 0.005           tcjsw   = 0.001           tpbswg  = 0.005           tcjswg  = 0.001         
+xtis    = 3               xtid    = 3             

+dmcg    = 0               dmci    = 0               dmdg    = 0               dmcgt   = 0             
+dwj     = 0               xgw     = 0               xgl     = 0             

+rshg    = 0.4             gbmin   = 1e-010          rbpb    = 5               rbpd    = 15            
+rbps    = 15              rbdb    = 15              rbsb    = 15              ngcon   = 1             


.model  pmos  pmos  level = 54


+version = 4.0             binunit = 1               paramchk= 1               mobmod  = 0             
+capmod  = 2               igcmod  = 1               igbmod  = 1               geomod  = 1             
+diomod  = 1               rdsmod  = 0               rbodymod= 1               rgatemod= 1             
+permod  = 1               acnqsmod= 0               trnqsmod= 0             

+tnom    = 27              toxe    = 1.62e-009       toxp    = 1.3e-009        toxm    = 1.62e-009     
+dtox    = 3.2e-010        epsrox  = 3.9             wint    = 5e-009          lint    = 0             
+ll      = 0               wl      = 0               lln     = 1               wln     = 1             
+lw      = 0               ww      = 0               lwn     = 1               wwn     = 1             
+lwl     = 0               wwl     = 0               xpart   = 0               toxref  = 1.6e-009      

+vth0    = -0.5808         k1      = 0.4             k2      = -0.01           k3      = 0             
+k3b     = 0               w0      = 2.5e-006        dvt0    = 1               dvt1    = 2             
+dvt2    = -0.032          dvt0w   = 0               dvt1w   = 0               dvt2w   = 0             
+dsub    = 0.1             minv    = 0.05            voffl   = 0               dvtp0   = 1e-011        
+dvtp1   = 0.05            lpe0    = 0               lpeb    = 0               xj      = 1e-008        
+ngate   = 1e+023          ndep    = 3.07e+018       nsd     = 2e+020          phin    = 0             
+cdsc    = 0               cdscb   = 0               cdscd   = 0               cit     = 0             
+voff    = -0.1            nfactor = 1.8             eta0    = 0.0115          etab    = 0             
+vfb     = 0.55            u0      = 0.016           ua      = 2e-009          ub      = 5e-019        
+uc      = 0               vsat    = 135000          a0      = 1               ags     = 1e-020        
+a1      = 0               a2      = 1               b0      = 0               b1      = 0             
+keta    = -0.047          dwg     = 0               dwb     = 0               pclm    = 0.12          
+pdiblc1 = 0.001           pdiblc2 = 0.001           pdiblcb = 3.4e-008        drout   = 0.56          
+pvag    = 1e-020          delta   = 0.01            pscbe1  = 8.14e+008       pscbe2  = 9.58e-007     
+fprout  = 0.2             pdits   = 0.08            pditsd  = 0.23            pditsl  = 2300000       
+rsh     = 5               rdsw    = 240             rsw     = 75              rdw     = 75            
+rdswmin = 0               rdwmin  = 0               rswmin  = 0               prwg    = 0             
+prwb    = 0               wr      = 1               alpha0  = 0.074           alpha1  = 0.005         
+beta0   = 30              agidl   = 0.0002          bgidl   = 2.1e+009        cgidl   = 0.0002        
+egidl   = 0.8             aigbacc = 0.012           bigbacc = 0.0028          cigbacc = 0.002         
+nigbacc = 1               aigbinv = 0.014           bigbinv = 0.004           cigbinv = 0.004         
+eigbinv = 1.1             nigbinv = 3               aigc    = 0.0097          bigc    = 0.00125       
+cigc    = 0.0008          aigsd   = 0.0097          bigsd   = 0.00125         cigsd   = 0.0008        
+nigc    = 1               poxedge = 1               pigcd   = 1               ntox    = 1             
+xrcrg1  = 12              xrcrg2  = 5             

+cgso    = 8.5e-011        cgdo    = 8.5e-011        cgbo    = 2.56e-011       cgdl    = 2.653e-010    
+cgsl    = 2.653e-010      ckappas = 0.03            ckappad = 0.03            acde    = 1             
+moin    = 15              noff    = 0.9             voffcv  = 0.02          

+kt1     = -0.11           kt1l    = 0               kt2     = 0.022           ute     = -1.5          
+ua1     = 4.31e-009       ub1     = 7.61e-018       uc1     = -5.6e-011       prt     = 0             
+at      = 33000         

+fnoimod = 1               tnoimod = 0             

+jss     = 0.0001          jsws    = 1e-011          jswgs   = 1e-010          njs     = 1             
+ijthsfwd= 0.01            ijthsrev= 0.001           bvs     = 10              xjbvs   = 1             
+jsd     = 0.0001          jswd    = 1e-011          jswgd   = 1e-010          njd     = 1             
+ijthdfwd= 0.01            ijthdrev= 0.001           bvd     = 10              xjbvd   = 1             
+pbs     = 1               cjs     = 0.0005          mjs     = 0.5             pbsws   = 1             
+cjsws   = 5e-010          mjsws   = 0.33            pbswgs  = 1               cjswgs  = 3e-010        
+mjswgs  = 0.33            pbd     = 1               cjd     = 0.0005          mjd     = 0.5           
+pbswd   = 1               cjswd   = 5e-010          mjswd   = 0.33            pbswgd  = 1             
+cjswgd  = 5e-010          mjswgd  = 0.33            tpb     = 0.005           tcj     = 0.001         
+tpbsw   = 0.005           tcjsw   = 0.001           tpbswg  = 0.005           tcjswg  = 0.001         
+xtis    = 3               xtid    = 3             

+dmcg    = 0               dmci    = 0               dmdg    = 0               dmcgt   = 0             
+dwj     = 0               xgw     = 0               xgl     = 0             

+rshg    = 0.4             gbmin   = 1e-010          rbpb    = 5               rbpd    = 15            
+rbps    = 15              rbdb    = 15              rbsb    = 15              ngcon   = 1             




Race conditions and glitches can and will happen, is a circuit that is insensitive to them (e.g. by ensuring suitable setup/hold times on your storage elements) not an option?

please do not post a picture of text ... post the text instead ... the picture cannot be easily copied and tested

@nanofarad Thank you for your response. In my circuit, I am using two identical pulse functions, and I am considering whether the slight delay might be due to differences in the number of MOS transistors that the two signals pass through, resulting in varying data paths.

@jsotola Thank you for your reminder. This is my first time in this community. I have updated the image to a link. Please feel free to leave a message if there are any issues.

@Mzm no link ... paste the text instead

Welcome to SE/EE! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works, and you might want to read some pages of the [help], too. Then come back and [edit] your question to add why you expect no glitches.

Are you positive an XOR guarantied to be glitch free when more than one input changes simultaneously is at all possible?

@greybeard hey it works if you gray code the test vector because only one input can switch at a time... :D

Those glitches are possibly capacitively coupled feed-through from the inputs directly to the output. The transistors' parasitic capacitances \$C_{GD}\$ and \$C_{DS}\$ are at fault, and are unavoidable in practical MOSFETs.
Things worsen with faster rising and falling input transitions, so one approach is to slow those down somewhat. In the simulator your input voltage sources have properties to control rise and fall time, so start there.
You should also try to reduce those parasitic capacitances. I'm not familiar with HSpice, and most of those MOSFET model parameters are foreign to me, but I suggest you play with Cgs* and Cds* to see what effect these have on the output glitches.

Thank you! Does this imply that, in practical implementations, it is impossible to achieve complete equivalence between the two input paths in a CMOS-based XOR gate due to the inherent influence of parasitic capacitances, which cannot be entirely ignored?

An XOR gate has what is called a functional hazard. If you change two inputs simultaneously, or near simultaneously, the gate may glitch, as in your simulation. This type of hazard cannot be fixed by changing the implementation of the gate. The "functional" in "functional hazard" is related to the fact that hazard is the result of the function you are implementing, not the way that it is implemented.
The first thing to consider is whether you need to implement the XOR function, or whether there is an alternative solution.
The second thing to consider is, if you need to use an XOR function, whether the remainder of the circuit can tolerate the glitch.
If you both need XOR functionality, and CANNOT tolerate a glitch, then you can consider methods to filter out the glitch. Glitch filtering will necessarily introduce some delay into your logic. A glitch filter basically implements the same functionality as a debounce circuit.
Here is an example.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Note that CircuitLab seems to not have a symbol for a Schmitt Trigger input, so I have simply annotated BUF1 stating that it has a Schmitt trigger input. The purpose of the Schmitt trigger is to square up the signal after it has been distorted by the RC network.
A possible shortcoming of this circuit is that the source of the glitchy input may have different current capabilities at high and at low signal levels. As a result, one might add diode and resistor, like so, to make the delays for rising and falling edges symmetrical.

simulate this circuit

From comments:

I would like to detect whether the logic of a circuit has been modified. My approach is to compare the output of the suspicious circuit with the output of a circuit that has the same structure. If the results are identical, it indicates that the logic has not been altered. Otherwise, it suggests that the logic within the circuit has been modified.

If the two circuits are clocked, then I would assume they run off the same clock, or you would have trouble. If that assumption is correct, you can latch the output of the XOR with timing appropriate to ensure that glitches are not latched.
If the two circuits don't have clocks, you may be able to use a circuit that treats the two outputs of your circuits as a quadrature encoded signal. Basically, that is the sort of signal used by an optical encoder (such as used in a "mechanical" computer mouse, or in many CNC machines). The circuit I am thinking of will set a flag if there is too much "jitter" between the two inputs, but will not flag simply because the transition on one input preceded the transition on the second input, as long as the second input "followed along". The two inputs can change place as to who is the "leader" and who is the "lagger", without raising the flag.

Thank you! That let me have another question. What other methods, apart from using an XOR gate, can be employed to ensure that two identical signal inputs result in a fixed output of 0 or 1?

@Mzm If two identical inputs result in a 1, and two different inputs result in a 0, that is an XOR gate. To (possibly) eliminate the XOR, one needs consider the larger picture. Why do you (think) you need that XOR gate output signal. What are you going to do with it. Perhaps the overall functionality can be achieved without the XOR, but I don't know the overall functionality.

I would like to detect whether the logic of a circuit has been modified. My approach is to compare the output of the suspicious circuit with the output of a circuit that has the same structure. If the results are identical, it indicates that the logic has not been altered. Otherwise, it suggests that the logic within the circuit has been modified.

@Mzm Are the circuits clocked? If they are clocked, I would assume they run off the same clock, or you would have trouble. If that assumption is correct, you can latch the output of the XOR with timing appropriate to ensure that glitches are not latched. If the two circuits don't have clocks, you need to decide how much skew there can be between the outputs of the two circuits. They will never have exactly synchronized outputs.

@Mzm I added some info to my answer. If you don't have clocks, and you want to know about the quadrature circuit that I mention, let me know, and I will try find/create something for you.

The circuit is in the same clk, I used DFF to try to sample the results to eliminate the glitch, but the output of DFF was somewhat unexpected, it went from 0.5VDD to zero in a short time. I don't want its output to start at 0.5VDD, I want it to be 0 all the time.
